# How to create a screen in android studio that saves latest push notifications sent via gcm

Tags: android-studio

In my application, whenever the push notification is viewed, previous message gets lost. I need to create a screen which would display all the notifications and when clicked on the notification, will show entire message. I am able to read complete latest message. I just need to store them

Comment: you need intent on your GcmListener
what is your listenerservice code

Comment: I have used this tutorial http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-multicast-push-notifications-using-gcm/

Comment: sorry late response...
this line you should fix:
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, GreetingActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("greetjson", greetMsg);

Comment: you need to grab content from your server...
[link[(http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)`volley may be good for you to read`

Comment: I did understand a little bit about volley. But the main part is to fetch the messages from the server. I also used list view so as to view all the messages but the app force stops all the time. I have difficulty understanding how to store the push messages into database so that i could fetch it into the app